# Singular homology of convex sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am have been asked to show that:
$$\text{If $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex, then $H_i(X)=0$ for all $i\gt 0$}$$
There is an obvious proof using homotopy invariance, but the question stipulates that I may not use this. Can someone suggest how I might go about proving this?

EDIT: I am only allowed to use the definition of simplicial homology in order to prove this.

Comment: I can only sympathise with you. Unfortunately as we don't know what tools you **are** allowed to use, it is hard to help. These questions asking to prove A without using B, seem very irritating to me (and I don't recall such questions from my undergraduate days many years ago). In doing new mathematics, one clutches at all available straws. If the instructor wants the students to exercise their understanding elementary methods (whatever that means), the instructor should say "using only methads P, Q, and R (or whatever), prove A.

Comment: The (n+1) simplex is the cone on the n simplex, i.e. we take a point outside of the simplex and join every point on the n simplex to this point with a line. So by picking a point in a convex set, we can naturally extend any map from an n simplex to an n+1 simplex. You might try investigating what happens when I take a cycle, and I do this process with each of its simplices.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, the way I have phrased this is unclear. In the context of the course, I am sure it means "using only the definition of singular homology", that is, finding a way to write every cycle as a boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to prove it using just the definition.

To clarify notation, let $\Delta^n=\{(x_0,\dots,x_n);x_i\geq0,\sum x_i=1\}$ be an $n$-simplex, we define singular $n$-simplices of a space $X$ to be maps $\Delta^n\to X$. We let $C_n$ be the free abelian group generated by the set of singular $n$-simplices and we define the boundary map $d_n:C_n\to C_{n-1}$ by, given a simplex $\sigma$, $d_n(\sigma)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\sigma\circ\delta_i$, where $\delta_i:\Delta_{n-1}\to\Delta_n;(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})\mapsto(x_0,\dots,x_{i-1},0,x_i,\dots,x_{n-1})$.

Now let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be convex, suppose $0\in X$. We will define a map $F_n:C_n\to C_{n+1}$ which associates to each simplex a cone based at that simplex and with a vertex in $p$: given an $n$-simplex $\sigma:\Delta_n\to X$, we define $F_n(\sigma):\Delta_{n+1}\to X;(x_0,\dots,x_n)\mapsto(1-x_0)\sigma(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Note that $F_n(\sigma)\circ\delta_0=\sigma$, and for $i>0$, $F_n(\sigma)\circ\delta_i=F_{n-1}(\sigma\circ\delta_{i-1})$.

So $d_{n+1}(F_n(\sigma))=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}(-1)^iF_n(\sigma)\circ\delta_i=\sigma-\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^iF_{n-1}(\sigma\circ\delta_i)$.

Now to prove that the homology is $0$, suppose that $(n_j)_{j=1}^k$ are integers and $\sigma_j$ are simplices, and $\sum_jn_j\sigma_j$ is a cycle. That is,

$$0=d_n\left(\sum_jn_j\sigma_j\right)=\sum_j\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^in_j\sigma_j\circ\delta_i.$$

Then consider the $n+1$-chain $\sum_j n_jF_n(\sigma_j)$. Then,

$$d_{n+1}\left(\sum_j n_jF_n(\sigma_j)\right)=\sum_jn_j\sigma_j-\sum_j\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^in_jF_{n-1}(\sigma_j\circ\delta_i)=\sum_jn_j\sigma_j,$$

so $\sum_jn_j\sigma_j$ is a boundary.